# windows sdk - Mavic 2 zoom - Bottom auxiliary lighting control

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to control the Bottom auxiliary lighting control via windows sdk. Right now I couldn't find any document relating to this topic. Anyone have an idea to how to control that light? I know that we can do it via the mobile app with custom button on the remote control. However, I cound't find any glue right now.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A document relating to this topic? That is not what stack overflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after read through all library. The setting for Bottom auxiliary lighting  is under GetFlightAssistantHandler class